# Debugging iOS/AIR content on the device

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop

I've created some flash content in FlashDevelop (v 4.0) that I've turned into an .ipa and put on the device. I would like to debug the content while it is running on the device because it is giving me some unexpected behaviour.

Is debugging AIR content on the physical device possible with FlashDevelop remote debugging? How to set that up?

Answer (score 2):

Yes remote debugging from FlashDevelop works with AIR iOS & Android projects (provided they share the same Wifi LAN):

- You need to edit the .Bat packaging script so the command would be:

  `adt -target ipa-debug-interpreter -connect -keystore [...]`

  `adt -target apk-debug -connect -keystore [...]`
- Then start FD remote debugging just before starting the app.

Comment: How do I do step 2? ("start FD remote debugging"). Do you have a feature by that name? Or do you mean FDB?

Comment: The answer was for FlashDevelop, which has in the main menu: Debug > Start Remote Session.